# How to comply with MIT licenses for third-party libraries in my GitHub project?

Tags: github, npm, licensing

I am planning to upload a project to GitHub, which I will later host on a web hosting service solely for the purpose of having a project in my portfolio. I am using the following third-party libraries in my project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "primereact": "^10.2.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
}
```

Should I add all the licenses of the libraries i used to a THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.txt file, and would that be sufficient?

Do I need to add anything to my source code?

Do i need to add anything to my LICENSE.md file if i don't mind if someone uses my code?

I haven't taken any specific actions yet regarding MIT license compliance for third-party libraries in my project. I'm seeking guidance on the best practices before proceeding.
I hope to gain insights into the recommended approach for handling MIT licenses associated with the third-party libraries in my project. Additionally, I want to ensure that my project is legally compliant, avoiding potential legal issues.
As of now, I haven't implemented any solutions, so there's no specific outcome to report. I'm looking for advice and direction on how to proceed correctly before uploading my project to GitHub.

Comment: Could you check if this answers your question? https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12933/spdx-and-copyright-notices-do-i-need-to-do-anything-about-dependencies